# Joining a variable inside a JSON formatted post request C++

Tags: c++, json, post, libcurl, put

So I have this put request which submits to a service running on localhost.
Doing it the way below works just fine, note I have replaced the actual acc name with ACC_NAME and password with ACC_PASSWORD.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_account_login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\r\n  \"username\": \ACC_NAME\,\r\n  \"password\": \"ACC_PASSWORD\,\r\n  \"persistLogin\": false\r\n}\r\n");
```

However when I wanted to pass in a variable containing the acc_name and acc_password, it does not work, I get an error response from server.
The below request is using the variable joined inside the JSON string, which gives me the error response.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_account_login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\r\n  \"username\": \""+acc_name+"\,\r\n  \"password\": \""+acc_password+"\,\r\n  \"persistLogin\": false\r\n}\r\n");
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong when I am joining the string variable into the request.
It works just fine by plain, if I write the account credentials directly into the request and not in a variable.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

C-style string literals (like `"something"`) are of type `const char []` (this is a null-terminated character array), which decays into a `const char*` (a pointer). Thus, `+` (as in `"something" + "another"`) is just adding two addresses, resulting in an invalid pointer value. You cannot concatenate C-style strings by simply using `+` that way.

Assuming you are using C++ (not C), as indicated by your question being tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I suggest C++ string objects instead, this will allow easy concatenation.

Also, there's a note in curl documentation about `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, mentioning that the data pointed to is not copied, thus requiring you to make sure the pointer remains valid until the associated transfer finishes. Because of that, I would prefer using `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead.

To sum up, do something like this:

```
#include <string>

// ...

std::string postfields
{
    std::string{ "{" } 
    + R"("username":")" + ACC_NAME
    + R"(","password":")" + ACC_PASSWORD
    + R"(","persistLogin":false})"
};

curl_easy_setopt(curl_account_login, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, postfields.data());
```